# How to obtain time-entries for a project?

Tags: clockify

An api exists for obtaining all time-entries for a workspace, /workspaces/{workspaceId}/time-entries, and the ability to obtain time-entries for a user, /workspaces/{workspaceId}/user/{userId}/time-entries.

- Can filtering be added to /workspaces/{workspaceId}/time-entries? Start Date would be nice.

Would be possible to add obtain time-entries for a project?

- /workspaces/{workspaceId}/projects/{projectId}/time-entries, with filtering of course

Answer (score 0):

For the new clockify report API, which is documented here (https://clockify.me/developers-api#tag-Reports), you can use following requests.

- Filtering time entries by user and date:

```sh
curl --request POST \
  --url https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/<YOUR WORKSPACE ID>/reports/summary \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'x-api-key: <YOUR API KEY>' \
  --data '{
    "dateRangeStart": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "dateRangeEnd": "2020-08-13T23:59:59.000Z",
    "summaryFilter": {"groups": ["USER", "TIMEENTRY"]},
    "exportType": "JSON",
    "users": {
    "ids": ["<USER ID>"],
    "contains": "CONTAINS",
    "status": "ALL"
  }
}'
```

- All time entries for a certain project:

```sh
curl --request POST \
  --url https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/<YOUR WORKSPACE ID/reports/summary \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --header 'x-api-key: <YOUR API KEY>' \
  --data '{
    "dateRangeStart": "2020-08-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "dateRangeEnd": "2020-08-13T23:59:59.000Z",
    "summaryFilter": {"groups": ["PROJECT", "TIMEENTRY"]},
    "exportType": "JSON",
    "projects": {"ids" : ["<PROJECT ID>"]}
}'
```

If you remove the group `TIMEENTRY` you will just get the sums as result, not all the separate time entries.

Of course you can fetch all time entries for a project grouped by a user like this (filtering by project and grouping by `USER`:

```
"summaryFilter": {"groups": ["PROJECT", "USER", "TIMEENTRY"]},
```